# Spring Boot : Submission of form in which rows can be added dynamically

Tags: jquery, spring, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a case where the user can add rows to the form dynamically and then submit those records by clicking the Submit button. For better visualization, see the demo here - http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/#adding-fields-with-same-names .The issue is that Spring is not binding the request to my Request class.

```
<form id="surveyForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Options</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The option field template containing an option field and a Remove button -->
    <div class="form-group hide" id="optionTemplate">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-5">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The maximum number of options
    var MAX_OPTIONS = 5;

    $('#surveyForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                question: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The question required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                'option[]': {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The option required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            max: 100,
                            message: 'The option must be less than 100 characters long'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        // Add button click handler
        .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
            var $template = $('#optionTemplate'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .insertBefore($template),
                $option   = $clone.find('[name="option[]"]');

            // Add new field
            $('#surveyForm').formValidation('addField', $option);
        })

        // Remove button click handler
        .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            var $row    = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                $option = $row.find('[name="option[]"]');

            // Remove element containing the option
            $row.remove();

            // Remove field
            $('#surveyForm').formValidation('removeField', $option);
        })

        // Called after adding new field
        .on('added.field.fv', function(e, data) {
            // data.field   --> The field name
            // data.element --> The new field element
            // data.options --> The new field options

            if (data.field === 'option[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="option[]"]').length >= MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        })

        // Called after removing the field
        .on('removed.field.fv', function(e, data) {
           if (data.field === 'option[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="option[]"]').length < MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addButton').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

My request class is as follows:

```
public class OptionsRequest implements Serializable  {

    private List<String> options;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The Controller class is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerOptions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerDepartmentsPost(OptionsRequest request) {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

Upon request submission, the exception stack trace is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processKeyedProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:275) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:834) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:730) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:915) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OptionsRequest` contains a list called `options`, so there is established naming convention. A server expects to receive data in a format like

```
options[0]=value1&options[1]=value2
```

but it would obtain

```
option[]=value1&option[]=value2
```

instead. This is happening because each added row contains an `<input>` with the same `name` attribute's value (`option[]`).

To fulfill the convention you should adjust your code, so that each row contains indexed options (`options[0]`, `options[1]`, ...) as its input's `name` attribute value. Please depend on [this example](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/#adding-fields-with-different-names), rather than the one you've posted.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I changed my form to follow the naming convention you mentioned and it worked.